# Как импортировать все функции из модуля, что бы не обращаться к ним через алиас?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pythonnet

Имеется `.NET` сборка `ControllerLibrary`, в ней имеется публичный модуль `General` в котором в свою очередь имеются публичные функции.

Данная сборка подгружается в `Python` скрипте следующим кодом:
Так же импортируется модуль `General`.

```
import clr
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

clr.AddReference("ControllerLibrary")
from ControllerLibrary import General as lib
```

> Вопрос: как импортировать все функции из модуля что бы не обращаться к
>   ним через алиас?

Варианты ниже не работают:

1)

```
from ControllerLibrary.General import *
```

*No module named 'ControllerLibrary'*

2)

```
from General import *
```

*No module named 'General'*

Comment: Вроде так должно работать: import ControllerLibrary; 
from ControllerLibrary.General import *

Comment: @anl ImportError : No module named 'ControllerLibrary.General'; 'ControllerLibrary' is not a package

Comment: Извините, а у вас вообще установлен данный модуль? В стандартных библиотеках python его просто нет

Comment: @DiHASTRO извините, а вы вообще вопрос читали?